# Get path of file being run after cd to another directory in python

Tags: python, shell

I have following simple script `test.py` in directory `/Users/apps`:-

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users/apps/update/diiferent_path")
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(path)
```

I am getting path value as `/Users/apps/update/diiferent_path` because I have changed the directory. How can I get test.py path i.e. `/Users/apps` after changing directory.

Comment: can't you save the path before chdir?

Comment: Will have to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do it after the `chdir` (unless, of course, if `__file__` already contains the absolute path), because the information is lost. There is no such thing as *what was the current directory when the process started* stored anywhere automatically. But you can store it manually by calling `os.path.abspath(__file__)` before calling the `chdir`.

Comment: Ok, That's what I thought before, but then searched a lot and finally posted here. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [pts post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323988/3146034) that storing the path is the way to go. It best shows your intention of getting the original path, despite what modifications are done throughout the script.

For reference sake two workarounds. The path changes because the script is executed by name. The interpreter then finds the file in the current directory. The current directory changes, and thus the absolute path of both `__file__` and `sys.argv`.

One way around that is to call the script with an **absolute path**. Another is to realize that the path of the script is **automatically added to the PYTHONPATH**, i.e. to `sys.path`. The following script illustrates that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

os.chdir("/usr/bin")
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
print(sys.path[0])
```

The output:

```
# /tmp$ ./so24323731.py 
/usr/bin/so24323731.py
/usr/bin/so24323731.py
/tmp
# /tmp$ /tmp/so24323731.py 
/tmp/so24323731.py
/tmp/so24323731.py
/tmp
```